# Expandable Listview does not refresh childs items (updated with solution)

Tags: android, android-listview, signalr, expandablelistview, listadapter

i have a signalr instances in my android app that allow me to refresh my expandable listview (just add or remove child items).

When i run my app in 2 differents mobiles at the begining it's works fine (adding or removing items in both sides) like i really want but when i start to navigate in differents activities and i repeat the same process that i did at the begining my signalr works(has new/updated list)  but my expandable listview does not refresh.

Here is my code:

My adapter:

```
public class rtDateAdapter extends AnimatedExpandableListView.AnimatedExpandableListAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private List<rtDay> items = new ArrayList<rtDay>();



    public rtDateAdapter(Context context, List<rtDay> days) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = days;
    }



    @Override
    public rtDates getChild(int DayPosition, int datePosition) {
        return items.get(DayPosition).getDates().get(datePosition);

    }

    public void refresh(List<rtDay> items)
    {
        this.items = null;


        this.items = items;
        **this.notifyDataSetChanged();**
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int dayPosition, int datePosition) {
        return items.get(dayPosition).getDates().get(datePosition).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getRealChildView(int dayPosition, int datePosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        rtDatesHolder holder;
        rtDates item = getChild(dayPosition, datePosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new rtDatesHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_item_date_layout, parent, false);
            holder.startDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStartDate);
            holder.finishDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFinishDate);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (rtDatesHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.startDate.setText(item.getTimeStart());
        holder.finishDate.setText(item.getTimeFinish());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRealChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition).getDates().size();
    }

    @Override
    public rtDay getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        rtDayHolder holder;
        rtDay item = getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new rtDayHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_header_fragment_layout, parent, false);
            holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderDay);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (rtDayHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.Name.setText(item.getName());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }

    private static class rtDatesHolder {
        TextView startDate;
        TextView finishDate;
    }

    private static class rtDayHolder {
        TextView Name;
    }
}
```

I try to use inside my adapter a method to force this.notifyDataSetChanged, but does not work.

this is my fragment:

```
public class DateFragment extends Fragment   {

    private View view;
    private List<rtDay> Days = new ArrayList<rtDay>();
    private Gson gson = new Gson();;
    private rtDateAdapter dateAdapter;
    private AnimatedExpandableListView listView;
    private int DoctorSelectedId;
    HubProxy scheduleHub;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_fragment_layout, container, false);




        DoctorSelectedId = KimchiDataCache.getInstance().pop(2);
        return  view;
    }

    public void onResume() {
        scheduleHub = HubConnectionFactory.getInstance().getHub();
        SubscribeUpdateDates(scheduleHub);
     .....

        Request request = rtRequestHttpFactory.GetRequestWithParameter(ServerURLServices.PATH_DATES, ServerURLServices.PARAM_FUNCTIONARY_ID, Integer.toString(DoctorSelectedId));
        try {
            String json =   new rtServerRequestBackground().execute(request).get();
            Days = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<rtDay>>(){}.getType());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        dateAdapter = new rtDateAdapter(getActivity(), Days);


        listView = (AnimatedExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listDaysAndDates);
        listView.setAdapter(dateAdapter);


        listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

                if (listView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    listView.collapseGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                } else {
                    listView.expandGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

        listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

               ......
            }
        });

        super.onResume();
    }




    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void SubscribeUpdateDates(HubProxy scheduleHub) {
        scheduleHub.on("UpdateDoctorDates", new SubscriptionHandler1<rtDay[]>() {

            @Override
            public void run(final rtDay[] days) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Days.clear();

                        for (rtDay h : days) {
                            Days.add(h);
                        }
                        dateAdapter.refresh(Days);

                        dateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //ONLY WORKS AT THE BEGING WHEN I RUN MY APP
                    }
                });
            }
        }, rtDay[].class);
    }

}
```

**Solution**

Well i finally fixed the problem, i change my fragment class to this:

```
public class DateFragment extends Fragment   {

    private View view;
    private List<rtDay> Days;
    private Gson gson;
    private rtDateAdapter dateAdapter;
    private AnimatedExpandableListView listView;
    private int DoctorSelectedId;
    HubProxy scheduleHub;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_fragment_layout, container, false);


        scheduleHub = HubConnectionFactory.getInstance().getChatHub();


        gson = new Gson();

        DoctorSelectedId = KimchiDataCache.getInstance().pop(2);
        JoinGroup(scheduleHub);
        SubscribeUpdateDates(scheduleHub);
        Request request = rtRequestHttpFactory.GetRequestWithParameter(ServerURLServices.PATH_DATES, ServerURLServices.PARAM_FUNCTIONARY_ID, Integer.toString(DoctorSelectedId));
        try {
            String json =   new rtServerRequestBackground().execute(request).get();
            Days = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<rtDay>>(){}.getType());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        dateAdapter = new rtDateAdapter(getActivity(),Days);


        listView = (AnimatedExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listDaysAndDates);
        listView.setAdapter(dateAdapter);

        // In order to show animations, we need to use a custom click handler
        // for our ExpandableListView.
        listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                // We call collapseGroupWithAnimation(int) and
                // expandGroupWithAnimation(int) to animate group
                // expansion/collapse.
                if (listView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    listView.collapseGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                } else {
                    listView.expandGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

        listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                rtDay day = Days.get(groupPosition);
                rtDates date = Days.get(groupPosition).getDates().get(childPosition);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reservando Cita: " + date.getTimeStart() + " - " + date.getTimeFinish(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                ActionDialogFragment dialog = ActionDialogFragment.newInstance(getActivity(), ActionEnum.SCHEDULEBYPACIENT, day.getName(),date.getId(),date.getTimeStart(),date.getTimeFinish());
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

                return false;
            }
        });


        return  view;
    }

    private void SubscribeUpdateDates(HubProxy scheduleHub) {
        scheduleHub.on("UpdateDoctorDates", new SubscriptionHandler1<rtDay[]>() {
            @Override
            public void run(final rtDay[] days) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {
 //THE PROBLEM WA HERE, getActivity().runOnUiThread WAS NULL SOMETIMES I GOT A NULLEXCEPTION(getActivity().runOnUiThread WAS NULL) BUT THE APP WAS STILL RUNNING SMOOTHLY DESPITE THIS, SO I JUST ADD IF STATEMENT BEFORE THIS AND FIX THE PROBLEM, NOW MY LISTVIEW REFRESH WITHOUT PROBLEM.
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Days.clear();
                        for (rtDay h : days) {
                            Days.add(h);
                        }
                        dateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
             }
                else{
                    Days.clear();
                    for (rtDay h : days) {
                        Days.add(h);
                    }
                    dateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }, rtDay[].class);
    }

    private void JoinGroup(HubProxy scheduleHub) {
        scheduleHub.invoke("JoinFunctionaryDatesGroup", DoctorSelectedId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
//        HubProxy Hub = HubFactory.getInstance().getScheduleHub();
        scheduleHub = HubConnectionFactory.getInstance().getChatHub();
        scheduleHub.invoke("LeaveFunctionaryDatesGroup", DoctorSelectedId);
        super.onPause();
    }


}
```

Comment: Your refresh method looks OK it should be refreshing the list, your issue must be on another place.

Comment: I would make a guess, that dateAdapter instance inside SubscribeUpdateDates isn't the dateAdapter you use with your listView

Comment: @pstrag yep, that is the problem :S , Now how can ireference the same adapter?

Comment: i try with a singleton adapter who return the same adapter but does not work, i dont know is my listview have to have the same references too..

Comment: Maybe try to create adapter in onCreate() function